# Inputting a string to sed for the "replaced text" field

Tags: bash, scripting, sed

I have a command that outputs some text that I would like to input to the sed's "replaced text" field. But I'm getting the

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unterminated `s' command error.
```

Here is the important snippet:

```
input=$(./mid 1 10 random.txt)       
echo $input       
cat $1 |sed "s/times/$input/g" > tester5.txt
```

And here is the command line output:

```
$ ./Batchtest tester.txt      
some random text some random text some random text some random text      
sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unterminated `s' command
```

As you can see the "./mid 1 10 random.txt" outputs some text that I want to plugin to sed's "replaced text" field, but it's not working. I've tried adding quotes around $input, but that doesn't help.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the code of `mid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With awk, you can put the output in a variable using the `-v` option. Using this method, you don't have to worry about characters special to sed's syntax in the output.

```
input=$(./mid 1 10 random.txt)
awk -v input="$input" '{ gsub(/times/,input); print }' "$1" > tester5.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

`$input` might contain some characters with special meaning for `sed`. You might try to quote them (i.e. prepend backslashes to them) or use a more advanced tool for the replacement, e.g. Perl:

```
perl -e '$input = `./mid 1 10 random.txt`;
         while (<>) {
             s/times/$input/g;
             print;
         }' "$1" > tester5.txt
```

Comment: Specifically, does `mid` output any newlines or carriage returns? Try piping `$input` through `hexdump` and look for '0x0a' or '0x0d'.

Comment: +1 on comment by @chepner - I'm pretty sure the `input=$(...)` construct will include the newline at the end.

Comment: @twalberg - That is not the case, the shell will strip blank newlines from the output.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I tried chorobas code and it worked. The mid program does have newline characters in it's output which was probably the cause of the problem. The mid program is an amalgam of head and tail to extract a specified number of lines from a txt file.